I need to pass the id for the summary and fetch the data of the particular person
Here is the summary code in ASP.NET Core:
public IActionResult Index()
{
     List<Order> order = _db.Order.GetAll().ToList();
     return View(order);
}

In this code, I need to get the summary based on the user raised records.
I need to fetch the data based on the id who raised the data or a records

You question is unclear. Please provide more information (as much as you can) in order to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve. For example; what is the relationship between Order and User? How do you know who has made the request to that endpoint?

Here is the detailed info.
I need to get the summary based on the logged-in user, showing only the data that the particular user has raised. otherwise it need to show the entire data that has been raised.

That’s not really more detail, just the same as your question but worded differently. What exactly are you struggling with? Do you know how to get the currently authenticated user? Please update your question and provide more specifics and all relevant code.

Do you mean to query the information of related users info based on a specific id? The summary you mentioned is not reflected in the code. How is it defined? Are there any related attributes?

You can use DbContext.Find Method to get a specific record from the database.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-8.0
